# How to get images "above the fold" right

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed

I have images above the fold and a pretty hard time getting them "right" for Google Pagespeed.

Markup roughly looks like this (dropped srcset and some irrelevant css)

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D&#039;http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg&#039; viewBox%3D&#039;0 0 748 429&#039;%2F%3E"
 data-lazy-type="image"
 data-lazy-src="../disaster-girl.jpg"
 width="748" height="429"
 class="lazy lazy-hidden"/>
<noscript>
  <img src="../disaster-girl.jpg" width="748" height="429" />
</noscript>
```

Asychronous loaded JavaScript later on swaps the attributes so the image appears. The classes only serve selection purposes.

The following screenshot is from Chrome Devtools with all external JavaScript and CSS removed from the page. Hence, this is what I expect PageSpeed to see above the fold:

[image: Devtools with JavaScript removed]

Instead, it complains and in fact, this is what Pagespeed sees above the fold:

[image: Pagespeed results without image and font icons]

The icon font is inline. No idea why Pagespeed does not see it. But the fact that the image does not appear at all really confuses me. I understand the logic could be made better by inline JavaScript setting the src attribute and shuffling display CSS of the first image, but I'd like to get "basic" stuff right first. :)

So first things first: Why does the image collapse in PageSpeed?